# Output a range of siblings in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an ODT document that I convert to HTML. That document has specific text fields that describe various *fields*. I use that to create emails. Now I would like to transform those to a PHP document.

The fields look like this:

```
<p><b>Day #0</b></p>
<p><b>Subject:</b></p>
<p>Here is a subject for Day #0</p>
<p><b>Body</b></p>
<p>A Paragraph One</p>
<p>A Paragraph Two</p>
<p>A Paragraph Three</p>
<p><b>Day #1</b></p>
<p><b>Subject:</b></p>
<p>Here is a subject for Day #1</p>
<p><b>Body</b></p>
<p>B Paragraph One</p>
<p>B Paragraph Two</p>
<p>B Paragraph Three</p>
<p>B Paragraph Four</p>
<p>B Paragraph Five</p>
<p><b>Day #3</b></p>
<p><b>Subject:</b></p>
[...etc...]
```

In XSTL, I am able to extract the Day Number and the Subject properly. However, I do not really see how I could extract all the Body paragraphs.

As we can see in my example above, in some cases there may be three and in other cases five paragraphs... it could be anything from one to *infinity* (zero is not an acceptable case, if that helps.)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/html/body/p[starts-with(b, 'Day #')]"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Extracting Day #, easy -->
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(., 'Day #')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(b, 'Day #')"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> =&gt; array(
</xsl:text>

<!-- Extracting Subject, easy -->
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">    "subject" =&gt; "</xsl:text>
<xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::p[2]/node()"/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">",
    "message" =&gt;
&lt;&lt;&lt;EOF</xsl:text>
<!-- Extracting Body, how can I copy all the siblings up to the next Day #? -->
<xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::p[4], following-sibling::p[5]"/>
<!-- I tried with this but it did not help...
      following-sibling::p[4] &gt;&gt; following-sibling::p[4]/b[starts-with(., 'Day #')]"/
-->
<xsl:text>
EOF
    ),
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected output has a header and a footer not shown here, but the final is a PHP script with an array of sub-arrays. The sample here presents what I would expect the XSLT code presented here to display:

```
0 => array(
    "subject" => "Here is a subject for Day #0",
    "message" =>
<<<EOF
<p>A Paragraph One</p>
<p>A Paragraph Two</p>
<p>A Paragraph Three</p>
EOF
),

1 => array(
    "subject" => "Here is a subject for Day #1",
    "message" =>
<<<EOF
<p>B Paragraph One</p>
<p>B Paragraph Two</p>
<p>B Paragraph Three</p>
<p>B Paragraph Four</p>
<p>B Paragraph Five</p>
EOF
),
...etc...
```

Note that I can have a comma (`,`) at the end of the list of entries. PHP allows such. However, the last entry will not be followed by a `"Day #123"`, although if too complicated to handle that special case, it is easy enough to add one more line in the source.

Note that paragraphs in the body may use other tags too, such as anchors (`<a>`), bold (`<b>`), and italic (`<i>`).

P.S. I am using Saxon version 9.1.0.8J on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: **1.** Please post the expected output. **2.** This seems to be a grouping question - try something like `<xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with="p[starts-with(b, 'Day #')]">`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Okay, I updated the question with output and some more details. I also fixed the `<xsl:text>` so the `&gt;` and `&lt;` appear as their corresponding characters and not the entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment to your question, this is a grouping problem. I believe the following stylesheet produces an output very close to the expected one:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/html">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="body/p" group-starting-with="p[starts-with(b, 'Day #')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(b, 'Day #')"/>
        <xsl:text> => array(&#10;"subject" => "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[3]"/>
        <xsl:text>",&#10;"message" =>&#10;&lt;&lt;&lt;EOF&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[position() > 4]">
            <xsl:text>&lt;p></xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&lt;/p>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>     
        <xsl:text>EOF&#10;),&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/93dEHFS/1

Comment: Yes! I was testing on my end, the `<xsl:for-each-group>` works as expected. This is great. Thank you.

Comment: Now that I have this working much better, I noticed that I also have `<ul>` tags at the same level. I just had to add that to the select as in: `select="body/(p|ul)"` and it works like a charm. (I already use a sub-template for the insertion of the paragraphs and lists, so I could add the `<p>` and `<ul>` as required there too.)